# Using the Facebook PHP-SDK, I cannot access individual videos

Tags: php, facebook, video, facebook-php-sdk

I am having a weird issue. Every time I try to read a specific video from FB, it tells me:

(#100) type must be one of the following values: tagged, uploaded

Which is odd, as the access token in this case IS ME, and I uploaded the video, so I SHOULD be able to read the data.

when I hit "/me/videos/uploaded" it returns a list of my videos, with the correct id's (I thought maybe I was using the wrong value).

here is the quick and dirty I am using to test

```
public function fbtestAction() {
    $code = $this->params()->fromQuery('code');
    $state = $this->params()->fromQuery('state');

    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => [add_id],
      'app_secret' => [app_secret],
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    if(!$code) {
        $permissions = ['user_videos'];
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://test.local/fbtest', $permissions);
        die("<a href='$loginUrl'>clickity</a>");
    } else {
        try {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } finally {
            echo '<pre>';
            //var_dump($fb->get('/me'));
            var_dump($fb->get('/me/videos/uploaded'));
            //var_dump($fb->get('/videos/[video_id]'));
            echo '</pre>';
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Reading comprehension for the win. The proper endpoint is "/[video_id]" not "/videos/[video_id]"